# Decimal Number Followed by a SINGLE 'E' Regular Expression in VBA Excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have to get all the entries in Excel having a decimal number or number followed by a single 'E'. For example: 9E, 5.6E, 6.78E...

After that, I'll remove that letter for another computation.

I have the code:

```
Dim strEarlyOut As String
strEarlyOut = "(\d+\.?\d*)([E])"

Dim regEx As New RegExp
Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With regEx
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .MultiLine = False
    .Pattern = strEarlyOut
End With

If regEx.Test(DayWeek1(x)) Then
    MsgBox "Day " & x & ": Early out!"

'Remove 'E' for computation
 NewDayWeek1(x) = Replace(DayWeek1(x), "E", " ")

End If
```

The problem is, upon running the code, entries such as:
8.90EEE, 7EL, 6.5LEEE, as long as it has 'E' and any number of 'E' equal to TRUE which i don't want to happen...

What is wrong with my pattern? I already tested making the pattern like this: "(\d+.?\d*)([E]{1})"

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: VBA is not VB.NET. Use the correct tag to reach the correct audience

Comment: Hello. I made a mistake on that. Thank you for the correction, Steve. :) @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Expression:

`^\d+\.?\d*?E$`

This will match strings that have only a single "E" at the end.